# Net Core API: Assigning Array name and showing in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I assign an array name to an Api?

Example: This has an array name called posts:
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/vocon-it.com/posts

```
"found":95,"posts":[{"ID":5551,"site_ID":97734730,"author":{"ID":5,"login":"oveits","email":false,"name":"oveits","first_name":"Oliver","last_name":"Veits","nice_name":"oveits","URL":"","avatar_URL":"https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/1364548d67e195a45f4d31cd84a4c826?s=96&d=identicon&r=g","profile_URL":"http:\/\/en.gravatar.com\/1364548d67e195a45f4d31cd84a4c826"},"date":"2018-12-20T20:10:29+00:00","modified":"2018-12-20T20:10:29+00:00","title":"Kubernetes (5) Local Persistent Volumes &#8211; A Step-by-Step Tutorial","URL":"https:\/\/vocon-it.com\/2018\/12\/20\/kubernetes-local-persistent-volumes\/","short_URL":"https:\/\/wp.me\/p6C5gC-1rx","content":"<p>Kubernetes local volume
```

My code does not have an array name so does not work. I am trying to publish my array api to Angular CLI, using resource template below. The issue is I need an array name.

```
[{"sysTablesId":0,"name":"Product","createDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"sysTablesId":0,"name":"book","createDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"sysTablesId":0,"name":"customertransaction","createDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},
```

**Front End Angular API:**

https://vocon-it.com/2017/06/24/consuming-a-restful-web-service-with-angular/

```
<h1>Table Data</h1>
<div *ngIf="undefined === restItems">Loading...</div>
<div *ngIf="undefined !== restItems">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of restItems['sysTables']" [innerHTML]="post.name">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRestItems();
  }
    // Read all REST Items
    getRestItems(): void {
      this.restItemsServiceGetRestItems()
        .subscribe(
          restItems => {
            this.restItems = restItems;
            console.log(this.restItems);
          }
        )
    }
      // Rest Items Service: Read all REST Items
  restItemsServiceGetRestItems() {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(this.restItemsUrl)
      .pipe(map(data => data));
  }
}
```

**Back End API:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ProductRepository productRepository;


    public ValuesController()
    {
        productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    }


    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<SysTables> Get()
    {
        return productRepository.GetAll();
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
    public IEnumerable<SysTables> GetAll()
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            return dbConnection.Query<SysTables>("SELECT * FROM sys.tables");
        }
    }

    public class SysTables
    {

        public int SysTablesId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }
```

The API works successfully in my VS code and Postman. Just calls a list of tables using Dapper in sql.

In Chrome it shows no results in html website, just an empty list, but at least showing its reading the API in F12 Console

[image]

Not working with this either yet,

```
<h1>Tables</h1>
<div *ngIf="undefined === restItems">Loading...</div>
<div *ngIf="undefined !== restItems">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of list">
      {{post.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of list" [innerHTML]="post.name">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please give more details of the error/issue you are facing. If the object is of the same type (has same properties), then the return value should automatically be assigned to the `restItem`.

Comment: are you getting the list of object in the response? as shown in the console?

Comment: correct, I receive a list of objects in console, want to display it to html now, If I have an array name like in the website example, I know it will prob work https://vocon-it.com/2017/06/24/consuming-a-restful-web-service-with-angular/

Comment: @HardyWest have added an answer, check once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

Use `*ngFor`:

```
<h1>Table Data</h1>
<div *ngIf="undefined === restItems">Loading...</div>
<div *ngIf="undefined !== restItems">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of restItems" [innerHTML]="post.name">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hey3re)